# How do I add "-" between items in a list for every possible combination?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Let's say I have a list `['a', 'b', '1', '2']`. I need to produce every possible combination of this list in the same order but adding a dash between the characters.

So I would need to produce all of the following answers:

```
a-b12
ab-12
ab1-2
a-b-12
a-b1-2
ab-1-2
a-b-1-2
```

I want to do this for a much longer string that will have many many more combinations. How can I do it?

Edit: Guys, all these comments have been so helpful! I greatly appreciate everyone helping me solve this than explaining it in such great detail!

Comment: What’s the context for this? It’s a potentially interesting problem.

Comment: I have a two programs, one will recognize the -'s and one wont. So i want one "account" on one end linked to hundreds on the other end.

Comment: Instead of worrying about the contents of the list, what is being done is to produce a list of all possible combinations of 0 (without `-`) and 1 (with `-`) of one less element than the outer list, and then intersperse this list into the original one.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I would check out the `"-".join(your_list)` and `.replace(old,new,count)` built in functions with a double `for` loop over `len(your_list)`

Comment: So far i have a For i in range(x) where x is the length of the string, and then I have 2 variables, one for before the dash and one after the dash. before always starts at 0 and after the dash = length of the string * -1. Then in the for loop, i have a = str(string[0:before] + '-' + string[after:].  Then i got into another loop after that separating the string into before the first - and doing the same thing. But this only gets me a fraction of the possible outcomes because it only does 2 -'s with one of them on the far right side, then 3 with only far right 2 and so on.

Comment: @BillSkiCO I'm not sure im following what your mentioning. I'm still a beginner. Could you post a small sample code with a small sample string that would achieve this?

Comment: @metatoaster even better, find all the possible sums for the length of the list, then use those to take list elements!

Comment: @metatoaster Do you have a link to somewhere i could go read about what your describing, or an example?  Thanks

Comment: Think of the slots (or commas) as a binary digit. In the above example, there are 3 binary digits. Iterate from 000 to 111 for all the possible combinations. Then replace the 1's by a dash. Simple?

Comment: @Spinor8 How do i associate each letter with binary, and then set it to count up and add a '-' if 1's and not to add '-' if 0's. I understand the logic behind what your saying but confused how to implement it.

Comment: John has implemented the idea as an answer below.

Comment: This should have been a quest for CodeGolf!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a   b   1   2
  ^   ^   ^
  |   |   |
  0   1   2
```

Imagine that every space between a character has an index. Between `a` and `b` is index 0. Between `b` and `1` is index 1. Between `1` and `2` is index 2.

Each space can have either a dash or nothing.

You want to check every combination of dash or nothing. If you think of each space as a "bit" where each bit can be 0 (empty) or 1 (dash), this maps quite nicely to checking all combinations of *b* bits, where *b* is one less than the number of items you have.

To check all bit combinations all you have to do is iterate from 1 to 2<sup>*b*</sup>. (Skip 0 to ensure there's always at least one dash.) For each iteration insert a dash whenever the corresponding bit is set.

Here's what it looks like if we're just emitting dashes or spaces, ignoring the `ab12` characters for now.

**Dashes only**

```
items = ['a', 'b', '1', '2']
bits  = len(items) - 1

for n in range(1, 2**bits):
    print(''.join('-' if n & (1<<i) else ' ' for i in range(bits)))
```

**Output**

```
-  
 - 
-- 
  -
- -
 --
---
```

There's a heck of a lot going on in those last two lines. Let me break it down.

- `for n in range(1, 2**bits)` — This is a direct translation of what I explained above. It loops from 1 to 2<sup>*b*</sup>. The only difference is I called it *bits* instead of *b*. Code benefits from using more descriptive variable names.
- `(<expr> for i in range(bits))` — A `for` loop inside parentheses is called a [generator expression](https://djangostars.com/blog/list-comprehensions-and-generator-expressions/). It's a compact way to generate a series of items in a single line of code. *expr* is evaluated for every value of *i*.
- `'-' if n & (1<<i) else ' '` — The *expr* above is this piece of work. It's the heart of the algorithm: for each space we either emit a `'-'` or a `' '`.     The cryptic bit `n & (1<<i)` is the [formula for testing if a bit is set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation).

  If you're not familiar with bitwise operations like `&`, bitwise AND, and `<<`, left shift, I encourage you to google for more information. It's a whole fascinating topic on its own that I could spend pages trying to explain.
- `''.join(...)` — This concatenates all the `'-'` and `' '` strings we're generating into one big string.

The final step is to intersperse the items and dashes. We can do that by adding a couple of bits to the code above. First, we'll prepend `items[i]` before each potential dash. Second, we'll add `items[-1]` to at the end. These two steps effectively surround the dashes with items from the list.

**Items and dashes**

```
items = ['a', 'b', '1', '2']
bits  = len(items) - 1

for n in range(1, 2**bits):
    print(''.join(items[i] + ('-' if n & (1<<i) else '') for i in range(bits)) + items[-1])
```

**Output**

```
a-b12
ab-12
a-b-12
ab1-2
a-b1-2
ab-1-2
a-b-1-2
```

Answer (score 2):

For clarity as opposed to speed:

```
def insert( seq ):
    answers = [] 
    if seq[1:]:
        for subseq in insert( seq[1:] ):
            answers.append( [ seq[0],    ] + subseq )
            answers.append( [ seq[0],'-' ] + subseq )
    else:
        answers.append( seq )
    return answers

for answer in insert(['a','b','1','2'])[1:]:
    print ''.join(answer)
```

Output is as desired (although I would have liked to output the no-dash solution, too):

```
a-b12
ab-12
a-b-12
ab1-2
a-b1-2
ab-1-2
a-b-1-2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple step-by-step solution. Its probably more inefficient than the other answers but its a straightforward approach.

You can first list all the binary combinations of `n-1` using [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

lst = ['a', 'b', '1', '2']

def binary_combinations(bits):
    return list(product([0, 1], repeat=bits))

binary_combs = binary_combinations(bits=len(lst) - 1)
# [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

Then you can intersperse your list with `''` between each item. This makes it easier to join later.

```
def intersperse(lst, item):
    result = [item] * (len(lst) * 2 - 1)
    result[0::2] = lst
    return result

interspersed_items = intersperse(lst, '')
# ['a', '', 'b', '', '1', '', '2']
```

Then finally you can output the combinations with replaced `-` and `str.join()` the result combination:

```
for comb in binary_combs[1:]:
    result = interspersed_items[:]

    for i, binary in enumerate(comb):
        if binary == 1:
            result[i * 2 + 1] = '-'

    print("".join(result))
```

Which outputs the following combinations. The following order is different than in the question, but that shouldn't be a problem?

```
ab1-2
ab-12
ab-1-2
a-b12
a-b1-2
a-b-12
a-b-1-2
```